# Why do we see black objects if they absorb all frequencies?

Tags: visible-light, thermal-radiation, vision

Black object absorb all frequencies, yet maybe some light is reflected anyway, but why do we see pitch black?

Comment: Does seeing nothing count as seeing? If no photons hit a part of your retina, you “see” black there.

Comment: What else would you expect to see? What alternative is there?

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "see." If the object is _perfectly_ black, then you will be unable to learn anything more by looking at it than you would be able to learn by looking at its shadow. It would look like a black hole---nothing for your eyes to focus on except its outline.  But you certainly would know that it was there because of how different it would look from all of the not-black things around it.

Comment: Most of the things that we call "black" are not _truly_ black. They really are just very dark shades of gray. (I.E., they reflect _some_ light, but not much of it.

Answer (score 1):

A black object absorbs light of all frequencies, but that doesn't mean that it absorbs *all* light at all frequencies.  Some is reflected.  Note that gray also absorbs (and reflects) all frequencies.

Comment: To add to this, it's partly up to the brain to decide how dark a gray color is. There's that famous illusion: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_shadow_illusion

Answer (score 0):

You would see even a perfectly black object if it *occulted* things behind it.

Human eyes detect photons, but the human visual system *perceives* **contrast**. You can "see" any object that contrasts enough with its background or surroundings, whether that's by reflecting/emitting more photons or fewer photons.

Answer (score 0):

Black objects do reflect some light, even our currently "blackest" substance [Vantablack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack) only absorbs about 99.965% of visible light. When we look at a black object the Photoreceptor cells in parts of our eyes light up a whole lot less, so our brains interpret it as black. We would therefore still be able to see even a [perfect black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body), (even though they don't exist).

Black objects based on it's emitted visible spectrum can be green, purple, white, etc. It's just that not enough of that light is absorbed by the cones and rods in your eye. An easy example of this are long exposure shots of the night sky, which are blue in a photo even though the nights sky looks black.

Comment: Vantablack is no longer the record holder. https://www.sciencealert.com/scientists-just-set-a-new-record-for-the-blackest-material-ever-created

Answer (score -3):

As I understood it, it's more a lack of intensity spectrum thing. You're not getting no photons, they're just random and not registering on cones of your eye because there's too little energy, too randomly dispersed including outside the normal visual spectrum, or a combination thereof.

Truly not getting any light back into your eye is Vantablack, a completely different phenomenon.